# Extract data from XML using ElementTree in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I have the following XML file, which I have to parse and extract data from it in a csv file. In this file I have two boxes (box_id), which are packed on two different parent objects (parent_box_id) and there are also the details of the content of each of the boxes (element sgtin -> info_sgtin).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doc>
    <info id_reference="2">
        <data_down>
            <tree>
                <box_id>046071598600870568</box_id>
                <parent_box_id>046071598600875594</parent_box_id>
            </tree>
            <tree>
                <box_id>046071598600870575</box_id>
                <parent_box_id>046071598600875595</parent_box_id>
            </tree>
            <tree>
                <sgtin>
                    <info_sgtin>
                        <sgtin>04607008133585B0SE1HVHBGR3A</sgtin>
                        <box_id>046071598600870568</box_id>
                        <gtin>04607008133585</gtin>
                        <series_number>026A</series_number>
                    </info_sgtin>
                </sgtin>
                <parent_box_id>046071598600870568</parent_box_id>
            </tree>
            <tree>
                <sgtin>
                    <info_sgtin>
                        <sgtin>046070081335856F7P78HBVBEH2</sgtin>
                        <box_id>046071598600870568</box_id>
                        <gtin>04607008133585</gtin>
                        <series_number>026A</series_number>
                    </info_sgtin>
                </sgtin>
                <parent_box_id>046071598600870568</parent_box_id>
            </tree>
            <tree>
                <sgtin>
                    <info_sgtin>
                        <sgtin>046070081335854T61H7CSXDE9W</sgtin>
                        <box_id>046071598600870575</box_id>
                        <gtin>04607008133585</gtin>
                        <series_number>026A</series_number>
                    </info_sgtin>
                </sgtin>
                <parent_box_id>046071598600870575</parent_box_id>
            </tree>
        </data_down>
    </info>
</doc>
```

For this purpose I decided to use Elementtree in Python, but the problem is that in my XML file I have two variants of  tag.

First of all I iterate through all the details and capture the box_id value, but after that I have to go to parent item and get the parent_box_id in which this box_id is packed.

In other words I want to get the data in the following way:

```
parent_box_id       box_id              sgtin                           series_number
046071598600875594  046071598600870568  04607008133585B0SE1HVHBGR3A     026A
046071598600875594  046071598600870568  046070081335856F7P78HBVBEH2     026A
046071598600875595  046071598600870575  046070081335854T61H7CSXDE9W     026A
```

But I can't figure out how to get parent_box_id value. Would appreciate any support from the community.

Here is the code that I have:

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

csv.writer(open('result.csv','w'),delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL))

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

with open('result.csv','a',newline='') as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for alist in root.iter('info_sgtin'):
    sgtin = alist.find('sgtin').text
    box_id = alist.find('box_id').text
    series = alist.find('series_number').text

    writer.writerow([sgtin,box_id,series])
```

Comment: the `parent_box_id` need to by matched with `box_id` inside first 2 `tree` and rest of data?

Comment: Hi @ZarakiKenpachi. Yes, you are right, in the beginning of XML we have a relations between box_id and parent_box_id, but in the details section we also have box_id and parent_box_id tags, which represent the same value, equal to box_id and for this one we have to identify the parent parent_box_id value from the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over every `<tree>` tag and check if there is data that you need. Then collect it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree


root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('data.xml')

# collect parent data
parent_data = {}
for item in root.iter('tree'):
    box_id_match = item.find('box_id')
    parent_box_id_match = item.find('parent_box_id')
    if box_id_match != None:
        parent_data.update({box_id_match.text: parent_box_id_match.text})

data = []
for item in root.iter('tree'):
    sgtin = item.find('sgtin/info_sgtin/sgtin')
    box_id = item.find('sgtin/info_sgtin/box_id')
    series_number = item.find('sgtin/info_sgtin/series_number')
    # collect valid data
    if sgtin != None and box_id != None and series_number != None:
        parent_box_id = parent_data.get(box_id.text)
        data.append([parent_box_id, box_id.text, sgtin.text, series_number.text])
```

**Output:**

```
['046071598600875594', '046071598600870568', '04607008133585B0SE1HVHBGR3A', '026A']
['046071598600875594', '046071598600870568', '046070081335856F7P78HBVBEH2', '026A']
['046071598600875595', '046071598600870575', '046070081335854T61H7CSXDE9W', '026A']
```

Comment: you actually specified parent_box_id value from the info_sgtin details (which is equal to box_id in this case), but it has to be looked up from the beginning of the file, where there is a relationship between box_id and parent_box_id.

Comment: When you try to collect the parent_data - you have the same tags in all "tree" elements and box_id_match and parent_id_match return values not only for the first two elements, where the aggregation is actually defined, but also for the details (where box_is is equal to parent_box_id).

Comment: @DenikGorbunov that is not true. Parent data will by collected only for tags that are defined just below tag `<tree>` like `<tree> --> <box_id>`. Rest of data will by handled as data to collect. Make test.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, with all your comments I understood how to get data from specific tags and check if they exist. I transformed the code itself, added some additional calls and I'm really happy that it finally works and solves the requirement. Appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using XPATH (first collecting the mapping between `box_id` and `parent_box_id` from the immediate children of `tree`). Is that what you are looking for? I am not sure since `046071598600875595` is listed in your desired output as `parent_box_id` for `box_id` `046071598600870575` and I don't know where this is coming from.

```
root = etree.parse(fp, parser)
parent_ids = {elem.text: elem.xpath("following-sibling::parent_box_id")[0].text
              for elem in root.xpath("//*/tree/box_id")}

for alist in root.iter('info_sgtin'):
    sgtin = alist.find('sgtin').text
    box_id = alist.find('box_id').text
    series = alist.find('series_number').text
    print(sgtin, parent_ids[box_id], box_id, series)
```

Output:

```
04607008133585B0SE1HVHBGR3A 046071598600875594 046071598600870568 026A
046070081335856F7P78HBVBEH2 046071598600875594 046071598600870568 026A
046070081335854T61H7CSXDE9W 046071598600875594 046071598600870575 026A
```

If your files were large and it made sense to only iterate through them once, then you could use `etree.iterparse` with `tag=["box_id"]` or `tag=["tree"]`. In the former case, check whether you observe the siblings that you would expect in either case (`sgtin`, `gtin`, `series_number` or `parent_box_id`). If you find `parent_box_id`, then you add a new mapping to your lookup table (a dictionary that links `box_id`s to `parent_box_id`s. If you find `sgtin` and others, write out the data you collect from the siblings and get the `parent_box_id` from your lookup table.

Of course the iterative solution as described can only work this way if the structure is as such that the `box_id` to `parent_box_id` mappings always preceed the collections of `sgtin`, `box_id`, `gtin` and `series_number`.

Comment: Hi @sim, Thanks for details provided. Actually here are some of the details on your question:  I am not sure since 046071598600875595 is listed in your desired output as parent_box_id for box_id 046071598600870575 and I don't know where this is coming from. - As you can see in the beginning of this XML there is a structure with the same tag <tree>, describing the relationships between box_id and parent_box_id elements and these details are from this part. These relations could be not always in the beginning of the file, but in any part as well ...

Comment: @DenikGorbunov: The sample data you provided das not contain the `parent_box_id` 046071598600875595 - I believe the output from my post should be correct given I understood the question correctly. The code posted works regardless of where the `<tree>`-elements are that contain the `parent_box_id` to `box_id` mappings. You'd have to decide based on your specific application needs whether it is too costly to iterate over the files twice or not.
Zaraki's solution has the advantage that the `parent_box_id`-element is not required to _follow_ `box_id`.

Comment: You are right, that was my mistake, sorry for this typo. I edited the initial XML file that I used as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doc>
    <info id_reference="2">
        <data_down>
            <tree>
                <box_id>046071598600870568</box_id>
                <parent_box_id>046071598600875594</parent_box_id>
            </tree>
            <tree>
                <box_id>046071598600870575</box_id>
                <parent_box_id>046071598600875594</parent_box_id>
            </tree>
            <tree>
                <sgtin>
                    <info_sgtin>
                        <sgtin>04607008133585B0SE1HVHBGR3A</sgtin>
                        <box_id>046071598600870568</box_id>
                        <gtin>04607008133585</gtin>
                        <series_number>026A</series_number>
                    </info_sgtin>
                </sgtin>
                <parent_box_id>046071598600870568</parent_box_id>
            </tree>
            <tree>
                <sgtin>
                    <info_sgtin>
                        <sgtin>046070081335856F7P78HBVBEH2</sgtin>
                        <box_id>046071598600870568</box_id>
                        <gtin>04607008133585</gtin>
                        <series_number>026A</series_number>
                    </info_sgtin>
                </sgtin>
                <parent_box_id>046071598600870568</parent_box_id>
            </tree>
            <tree>
                <sgtin>
                    <info_sgtin>
                        <sgtin>046070081335854T61H7CSXDE9W</sgtin>
                        <box_id>046071598600870575</box_id>
                        <gtin>04607008133585</gtin>
                        <series_number>026A</series_number>
                    </info_sgtin>
                </sgtin>
                <parent_box_id>046071598600870575</parent_box_id>
            </tree>
        </data_down>
    </info>
</doc>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
boxIds = doc.selects('data_down>tree').notContains('<sgtin>')
dic = {}
for box in boxIds:
    dic[box.box_id.html]=box.parent_box_id.html
datas=[]
boxs = doc.selects('data_down>info_sgtin')
for box in boxs:
    datas.append([dic[box.box_id.html],box.box_id.html,box.sgtin.html,box.series_number.html])

print (datas)
```

Result:

```
[['046071598600875594', '046071598600870568', '04607008133585B0SE1HVHBGR3A', '026A'], ['046071598600875594', '046071598600870568', '046070081335856F7P78HBVBEH2', '026A'], ['046071598600875594', '046071598600870575', '046070081335854T61H7CSXDE9W', '026A']]
```

Comment: Thanks @dabingsou, this is really great Solution as well. Will take a not of this one.